# Prevent Text File From Being Deleted When Accessed From Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, io

I'm trying to debug a problem that just surfaced in my program. Until now, I've been writing, reading and updating props file with no problem using the following code structure:

```
public void setAndReplacePropValue(String dir, String key, String value) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    if (value != null) {
     File file = new File(dir);
     if (!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File: " + dir + " is not present. Attempting to create new file now..");
                new FilesAndFolders().createTextFileWithDirsIfNotPresent(dir);
     }

     if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(fileInputStream);
                fileInputStream.close();

              if (properties != null) {
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                properties.setProperty(key, value);
                properties.store(fileOutputStream, null);
                fileOutputStream.close();
                }
            }   
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
            System.out.println("File: " + dir + " does not exist and attempt to create new file failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

However, recently I noticed that a specific file (let's call it:  `C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\props.txt`) is being deleted after being updated from multiple threads. I'm not sure the exact source of this error, as it seems to happen randomly.

I thought that, perhaps, if two threads call `setAndReplacePropValue()` and the first thread calls  `FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);` before it has a chance to re-write data to file (via  `properties.store(fileOutputStream, null)` ) then the second thread might call `fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);` on an empty file - causing the thread to delete previous data when writing 'empty' data back to file.

To test my hypothesis I tried calling `setAndReplacePropValue()` from multiple threads several hundred to thousand times in a row while making changes to `setAndReplacePropValue()` as needed. Here are my results:

1. If `setAndReplace()` is declared as `static` + `synchronized` the original `props` data is preserved. This remains true even when I add a random delay after calling `FileOutputStream` - as long as JVM exists normally. If JVM is killed/terminated (after `FileOutputStream` is called) then previous data will be deleted.
2. If I remove both `static` and `synchronized` modifiers from `setAndReplace()` and call `setAndReplace()` 5,000 times, the old data is still preserved (*why?*) - as long as JVM ends normally. This appears to be true even when I add random delay in `setAndReplace()` (after calling `FileOutputStream`).
3. When I try modifying props file using `ExecutorService` (I occasionally access `setAndReplacePropValue()` via `ExecutorService` in my program), file content is preserved as long as there's no delay after `FileOutputStream`. If I add delay and the delay is > 'timout' value set in future.get() (so `interrupted exception` is thrown) the data is **NOT** preserved. This remains true even if I add `static` + `synchronized` keywords to method.

In short, my question is what is the most likely explanation for why file is being deleted? (I thought point 3 might explain error but I'm not actually `sleeping` after calling `new FileOutputStream()` so presumably this would not prevent data from being written back to file after calling `new FileOutputStream()`). *Is there another possibility I didn't think of?*

Also, why is **point 2** true? If method is not declared as static/synchronized shouldn't this cause one thread to create `InputStream` from empty file?  Thanks.

Comment: Why not have all threads post the data to be written to a blocking queue, and then use one single thread to read from this queue and write to the file?

Comment: `static` makes no difference here -- it only decides whether the method has access to fields of an instance off the enclosing class.

Comment: Just to make sure, it's not that the _file_ is being deleting, it's that the file gets emptied, right?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is very difficult to provide feedback on your code without a ton of additional information but hopefully, my comments will be helpful.

In general, having multiple threads reading and writing from the same file is a really bad idea.  I can't agree more with @Hovercraft-Full-Of-Eels who recommends that you have **1** thread do the reading/writing and the other threads just add updates to a shared `BlockingQueue`.

But that said here are some comments.

> If setAndReplace() is declared as static + synchronized the original props data is preserved.

Right, this stops the terrible race condition in your code where 2 threads could be trying to write to the output file at the same time.  Or it could be that 1 thread *starts* to write and another thread reads an empty file causing data to be lost.

> If JVM is killed/terminated (after FileOutputStream is called) then previous data will be deleted.

I don't quite understand this part but your code should have good try/finally clauses to make sure that the files are closed appropriately when the JVM terminates.  If the JVM is hard-killed then the file may have been opened but not be written yet (depending on timing).  In this case, I would recommend that you write to a temporary file and *rename* to your properties file which is atomic.  Then you might miss the update if the JVM is killed but the file will never be overwritten and be empty.

> If I remove both static and synchronized modifiers from setAndReplace() and call setAndReplace() 5,000 times, the old data is still preserved (why?)

No idea.  Depends on race conditions.  Maybe you are just getting lucky.

> When I try modifying props file using ExecutorService (I occasionally access setAndReplacePropValue() via ExecutorService in my program), file content is preserved as long as there's no delay after FileOutputStream. If I add delay and the delay is > 'timeout' value set in future.get() (so interrupted exception is thrown) the data is NOT preserved. This remains true even if I add static + synchronized keywords to method.

I can't answer that without seeing the specific code.

This would be a good idea actually if you had a fixed thread pool with 1 thread, then each of the threads that want to update a value would just submit the field/value object to the thread-pool.  This is approximately what @Hovercraft-Full-Of-Eels was talking about.

Hope this helps.